# On posting a form in MVC how do I have the controller open a new window with results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink("pSearch", "Results", null, new {target="_blank"})
```

doesn't work because it doesn't post the form data to the "Results" controller action and all that is returned is a 404 error.

Comment: actionLink will produce an <a> tag that would not post the form.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  An action link like you are using initiates a get method.  If you are trying to do a form post you should expand your example to show the form and input ie. @using (Html.BeginForm()) and <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log On" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

then:

```
@Html.ActionLink("pSearch", "Results", null, new { target="_blank" })
```

will generate:

```
<a href="/Home/Results" target="_blank">pSearch</a>
```

So if you expect to get anything else than 404 hopefully you have defined a `Results` action inside `HomeController`, have you?

Like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Results()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can't really expect much more than a 404 error, can you?

it's obvious, but probably worth mentioning, that this action will expect `~/Views/Home/Results.cshtml` or `~/Views/Home/Results.aspx` view to be defined. You have defined it in this location, haven't you?

Comment: I added onclick="this.form.target = '_blank'; return true;" to the submit button and all is well. I was making it much more complex then it really needed to be I guess. (forgot my basic html)

Comment: Yeah, don't forget basic HTML. Remember that all that ASP.NET MVC does is at the end of the day is spit a couple of bytes of HTML which are are consumed by a client browser. So don't think in terms of ASP.NET MVC. Think in terms of what does the browser sees at the end of the day.